# Eclipse - RCP Application does not see/recognize my plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plugin for an Eclipse RCP application. When I test my plugin from inside Eclipse (version 2018-12), it works. But when I export that plugin (File -> Export -> Plug-in Development -> Deployable plug-ins and fragments) as jar file, and copy that jar file to my RCP application's Plugins folder, the RCP application does not load my plugin.

The exported jar file contains all my classes, META-INF folder with MANEFEST.MF file, and plugin.xml file.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just copying to the plugins folder is not a supported way of adding plug-ins as Eclipse does not look there for new plug-ins. You can either do a proper install or put the plug-in in the 'dropins' directory (assuming your RCP includes the plugins that check for updates).

Comment: I will check it out, how the RCP application suggests adding a plugin.